# set the body height width css expressions

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-expressions

I want to change the body height dynamically using css expression.. my code is

**HTML**

```
<body >
 <div class="tall_top" >

 </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
     width:      100px;
     height:     expression(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
     background: red;
   }
 .tall_top { 
   background:#f1f1f1; 
   width:50%; 
   height:50%
  }
```

But It is not working in google chrome..... The inner div is not displaying. The height of body displaying in inspect element is 0px;

**JS Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/3x6fh/

Comment: which browser and version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div.tall_top` does not show up because your `body,html` does not have a height.

Set the height to `100%`

```
    html,body {
        margin:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background:blue;
    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/3x6fh/2/

Answer (score 1):

css expressions is not worth learning any more. use JavaScript or [css media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). and also it will create the browser compatibility issue since it is only supported   only ever IE6/7 (maybe) 5.

[High Performance Web Sites: Rule  – Avoid CSS Expressions](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_6/)

Comment: They never were worth learning. Aren't they IE-only features as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your `expression` essentially evaluates to the height of the window, which is usually the height of the `<html>` element.

Adding this CSS should work:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```